# How do I preview changes in real time to the user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, web-applications

I'm making an application using Laravel and React. I want the user to be able to see a mobile preview of changes he makes on his profil in real time, like changing his name and automatically having a preview of his profil with the name changed or background. How to do so ?

I'm a little bit familiar with websockets in Laravel but I believe it's a frontend thing rather than backend so I should be using another thing.

*Edit: Now that I'm writing here on Stack, think like the preview box for my text, the changes are made instantly to see the preview.*

Comment: We can't tell without any code. You're using React, so a lot of the business logic is already written. Have you tried something yet? If so, please include the attempt. What does a *mobile preview* mean?

Comment: @Emiel Zuurbier Unfortunately I didn't implement React yet in my Laravel project. I'm trying to understand first. See this example https://i.imgur.com/j69iNL7.png . The name is previewed instantly on the phone interface. Something like that.

Comment: Ah, okay. React is the right candidate for this particular job. You'd want to look into the Context API to make, for example, the value of your text field available in other components in your application, like in your mobile preview. Then whenever the value of the textbox is changed, the value of the preview changes with it.

Comment: Riiight. So everything is in real time then right ?

Comment: Definitely. it's exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much I will dive into it immediately.